# Apache Solr - Multiple values per field

Tags: solr

I'm a Sor newbie, my apologies if this question is too basic or doesn't make any sense.

I'm trying to implement a multi faceted search and I followed the [example](https://yonik.com/multi-select-faceting/) on Yonik's site.

My application can have any number of multiple values per item which are currently concatenated using the pipe symbol, see image.

[image]

I'm not sure whether concatenation is the best method.

My query is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/products/select?
q=structure_s:*/saxophones/alto*&
fq={!tag=LEVEL}Level_s:Student&
json.facet={
    Brand:{type:terms,field:Brand_s},
    Finance:{type:terms,field:Finance_s},
    Finish:{type:terms,field:Finish_s},
    Level:{type:terms,field:Level_s},
    Price:{type:terms,field:Price_s},
    Sale:{type:terms,ield:Sale_s}
}
```

Can someone give point me in the right direction or tell me how they would do it?

Many thanks!